# Having an error reading a text file with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've been trying to learn how to read a text file locally using JavaScript and Ajax. I've been looking on some tutorials online, and have followed them, but no matter what I do I cannot get my text to display what is in the .txt file.

```
function loadDoc(){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","names.txt",true);
                        allText = xmlhttp.responseText; 
                        lines = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.send(null);

                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=allText;
            }
```

I think this is meant to change the div I have (id "myDiv") to read what is in the text file, but it does not seem to do this, no matter what I try. Any help would be appreciated - I'm still new to JavaScript and Ajax.

Comment: If it doesn't show your text then what is it showing now. Have you seen it on developers tool or in firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to make sure that the AJAX call is returning the correct text.

Is `names.txt` in the same directory as the HTML page?